# How to do a case insensitive switch in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am trying to do a case insensitive match, if possible also apply a regex so any sentence containing a search word will retrieve the result.

The current "switch":

```
def movement(i):
    switcher = {
        'Automatik': 6,
        'Handaufzug': 12}
    return switcher.get(i, "Invalid movement " + i)

watch['movement'] = movement(value)
```

The method should return 6 in all of the following cases:

- Automatik
- automatik
- Automatik Winding
- Winding Automatik
- ...

Is this possible with Python?

Comment: To make a string lower case there is `str.lower()` (for case-insensitive comparison). To test if string `a` is in `b` there is `a in b`.

Comment: Tokenize your input string into the words and search each lowercase word in the lowercase keys of the dict.

Answer (score 1):

a slight variant from The Pineapple's:

```
def movement(my_string):
    switcher={
        'automatik' : 6,
        'handaufzug' : 12
     }
    for k, v in switcher.items():
        if k in my_string.lower():
            return v
    return None


for phrase in ['Automatik','automatik','Automatik Winding','Winding Automatik','negative automatico']:
    print('in:{} \tout:{}'.format(phrase,movement(phrase)))
```

.

```
in:Automatik    out:6
in:automatik    out:6
in:Automatik Winding    out:6
in:Winding Automatik    out:6
in:negative automatico  out:None
```

Comment: That is a good solution. I tried to make a minimal example and somehow you firgured out a way without regex. The problem also is, that there are many words for automatik. So I am trying to match various. Is there a possiblility to use regex? e.e. 'automatik|automatic|anything' :6

Comment: @merlin i'm not very fluent in regex, but i do know regex is very powerful, so most likely yes. Alternatively, just expand the dictionary to have `'automatic':6`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that i is a string, you should be able to do the following. While it is not the most elegant or robust solution, it should get the job done.

```
def movement(i):
    switcher={
        'automatik' : 6,
        'handaufzug' : 12
     }
    for word in my_string.split():
        temp = switcher.get(word.lower(), None)
        if temp is not None:
             return temp
    return None

watch['movement']  = movement(value)
```

Hope this helps.